How to define an Optional[Decimal] field in python sqlmodel library that yields to constrained JSON schema
I have the following sqlmodel base class and table models but I can't manage to make my Decimal field optional while keeping the constraints.
PS: I already know this has been discussed for pydantic already but the solution seems not to be working with sqlmodel.

First try (Error: ValueError: Unknown constraint max_digits)

class ItemBase(SQLModel):
  # ...
  price: Optional[Decimal] = Field(
    default=None, max_digits=7, decimal_places=4, ge=0, le=100
  )
  # ...

class ItemTable(ItemBase, table=True):
  __tablename__ = "item"
  # ...


Pydantic solution says to apply constraints only to Decimal (https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/7962#discussioncomment-7939114) In sqlmodel it yields to error: TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

class ItemBase(SQLModel):
  # ...
  price: Optional[Annotated[Decimal, Field(
    default=None, max_digits=7, decimal_places=4, ge=0, le=100
  )]] = None
  # ...


My solution for the code to work was to use sa_column for the max_digits and decimal_places constraints, that's okay because this really matters mostly on the database side.

class ItemBase(SQLModel):
  price: Optional[Decimal] = Field(
    default=None, ge=0, le=100, sa_column=Column(DECIMAL(7,4)),
    regex=r"^\d+(\.\d+)?$"  # added for the string part to only accept numbers
  )

With that last attempt, the le and ge constraints work properly in python:
ItemTable(..., price=Decimal(123.45))  # => throws ValidationError
ItemTable(..., price=Decimal(34.12))  # => works fine

But now my problem is that the json schema generated with that drops all my constraints to become only:
anyOf: [{type: number}, {type: string}, {type: null}]
Problematic because I am then using the json schema for creating fake objects (with the jsf library) for my tests and without the constraints my tests all fail...
Edit with an answer:
Thanks to @Jeremy I figured that the error stated in point 2 only occurs for table=True models. So I ended up doing the following:
class ItemBase(SQLModel):
  # ...
  price: Optional[Annotated[Decimal, Field(
    multiple_of=0.0001, ge=0, le=100
  )]] = None
  # ...

class ItemTable(ItemBase, table=True):
  price: Optional[Decimal] = Field(
    default=None, ge=0, le=100, sa_column=Column(DECIMAL(7,4)
  )

In order to add a pattern constraint to the string type of the decimal json model I had to subclass pydantic's GenerateJsonSchema:
class MySchemaGenerator(GenerateJsonSchema):
  def decimal_schema(self, schema: core_schema.DecimalSchema) -> JsonSchemaValue:
    json_schema = self.str_schema(core_schema.str_schema(pattern=r"^[-+]?\d+((?:\.\d+)|(?:[eE][-+]?\d+))?$"))
    ... # the rest of the method is unchanged

ItemBase.model_json_schema(schema_generator=MySchemaGenerator)
"""returns for 'price' property:
{'price': {'anyOf': [{'maximum': 100.0,
     'minimum': 0.0,
     'multipleOf': 0.0001,
     'type': 'number'},
    {'pattern': '^[-+]?\\d+((?:\\.\\d+)|(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+))?$',
     'type': 'string'},
    {'type': 'null'}],
   'default': None,
   'title': 'Price'}
"""

But this way I can't specify the pattern directly on a field and so all decimal will have the same pattern. If someone has an idea on how to pass a regex from the field definition to that decimal_schema method I would gladly take it!

What version of sqlmodel are you using?

Versions are as follow: sqlmodel==0.0.16 and pydantic==2.6.4

Try this

0 is equivalent to default = 0
multiple_of gives you the precision requirement as a divisible
le gives you the maximum integer value

class ItemBase(SQLModel)
  price: Optional[Annotated[Decimal, Field(0, multiple_of=0.0001, le=1000000)]] | None

it should produce a schema something like this
{
    "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "maximum": 1000000,
            "multipleOf": 0.0001
        }
    }
}

This will validate a number up to 7 digits and if a decimal value is provided, should validate up to four(4) precision points.
456123.1235
If that still fails, there's quite a few SO answers indicating the typing-extensions package may need to be upgraded.
pip install --force-reinstall typing-extensions==4.5.0
I haven't dug deeper than that but I wonder if pydantic is having some difficulty generating the JSON Schema due to conflicting keywords between the type defined and the constraints as something like max_digits is equivalent to maxLength which is a constraint for type: string values.

Thanks, it helped me understand a bit more. It seems my problem issubclass() arg 1 must be a class is coming from sql alchemy when i set table=True.
typing-extensions last version seems to be 4.11.0 however.
And the problem for me really was that the constraints no matter which were just removed.
If you can additionally tell me how to add the regex as a string pattern ? (:

I got how to do that last part, overriding GenerateJsonSchema.decimal_schema method made the trick. I'll make a full answer in my question. Thanks for your help in pointing me to the good direction.
